# Related information about location in freebase are always null?

Tags: freebase

I'm trying to query freebase to find information about a specific city.

I'm able to find the city that I'm looking for but I need to get the description content as well as a few pictures.

My current query is

```
[{
  "name":   "san francisco",
  "id":     null,
  "type":   "/location/citytown",
  "/location/location/geolocation" : [
    {
      "latitude": null,
      "longitude": null,
      "latitude>" : 36,
      "latitude<" : 38 }]
  "/common/topic/article" : [{ "id" : null, "content": null }],
  "/common/topic/image" : [{
   "id" : null,
   "optional" : true,
   "limit" : 15
  "image_caption" : []
  }]
}]
```

Which returns

```
{
  "code":          "/api/status/ok",
  "result": [{
    "/common/topic/article": [{
      "content": null,
      "id":      "/m/0d6l_"
    }],
    "/common/topic/image": [
      {
        "id":            "/m/02929wx",
        "image_caption": []
      },
      {
        "id":            "/m/04j74y4",
        "image_caption": []
      },
      {
        "id":            "/m/04j74yh",
        "image_caption": []
      },
      {
        "id":            "/m/04j74yw",
        "image_caption": []
      },
      {
        "id":            "/m/04j74z6",
        "image_caption": []
      }
    ],
    "/location/location/geolocation": [{
      "latitude":  37.775,
      "longitude": -122.4183
    }],
    "id":   "/en/san_francisco",
    "name": "San Francisco",
    "type": "/location/citytown"
  }],
  "status":        "200 OK",
  "transaction_id": "cache;cache03.p01.sjc1:8101;2012-07-24T21:50:06Z;0029"
}
```

I can't get the content value and the captions to be set.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2):

Where did you find the "image_caption" property?  If you switch it to "name" you should get the names of the images (which are used as captions in some UI contexts).

The text content isn't available from MQL, but you can get it from the BLOB service in the old API or the text API in the new APIs using the ID that is returned for the article. e.g. https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/text/m/0d6l_

p.s.  If you just want the primary image, you might consider using the Topic API which will return you the image, it's name, the text blurb, and a bunch of other info in a single call.
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/wikipedia/en_id/49728

Using the Search API will give you more robust name matching as well as give you a score which  will tell you how likely it is that the query is ambiguous (if you get multiple matches with scores close to each other).
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=%22san%20francisco%22&type=/location/citytown

Comment: Image caption exists but its not set frequently apprently.Name is sufficient for me thanks ! I still need the article content value too